# python requests verify SSL certificate

Tags: python, flask, openssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to pull data from an API which is secured by SSL. I wrote a python script to pull the data. Beforehand I have to convert a .p12 file to an openSSL certificate. When I use the following code it works just fine:

```
# ----- SCRIPT 1 -----
def pfx_to_pem(pfx_path, pfx_password):
    ''' Decrypts the .pfx file to be used with requests. '''
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pem') as t_pem:
        f_pem = open(t_pem.name, 'wb')
        pfx = open(pfx_path, 'rb').read()
        p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(pfx, pfx_password)
        f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))
        f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))
        ca = p12.get_ca_certificates()
        if ca is not None:
            for cert in ca:
                f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
        f_pem.close()
        yield t_pem.name

# read some config
with open('config.json') as config_json:
    config = json.load(config_json)
    api_url = config['api_url']
    cert = config['cert']

    cert_pem_path = cert['file']
    cert_key_file = cert['pass']

# make the request
with pfx_to_pem(cert_pem_path, cert_key_file) as cert:
    r = requests.get(api_url, cert = cert)
```

Because I'm also using the same functionality to authenticate my Flask web service towards the server I split up the cert file into three files:

```
# ----- SCRIPT 1 -----
# get certificate
f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(
    OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate())
)

# get keyfile
f_key.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(
    OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey())
)

# get CA_BUNDLE
ca = p12.get_ca_certificates()
    if ca is not None:
        for cert in ca:
            f_ca.write(
                OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(
                    OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert
            ))
```

Then I'm running the web service with the following code:

```
# ----- SCRIPT 2 -----
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.load_verify_locations(cert_ca)
context.load_cert_chain(cert_pem, cert_key)

app.run(ssl_context = context, host = '0.0.0.0')
```

and changed the requests call to

```
# ----- SCRIPT 1 -----
r = requests.get(api_url, cert = (cert_pem, cert_key), verify = cert_ca)
```

When trying to pull data from the API I get the error

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='some.host', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /some/path/var?ID=xxxxxx (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:847)'),))
```

---

Question 1: What am I doing wrong creating the CA_BUNDLE?

Question 2: Am I handling the creation of the web service correctly? My goal is to verify my server against the server holding the data to eventually be able to receive the data by push request.

EDIT: when connecting to my web service (in a browser) I receive the warning that the connection is not secure, because the certificate is not valid, despite the fact that I imported the .p12 certificate into my browser.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm using the request and json library to call API, in my case I can set-up the request to ignore the certificate and this quickly solved my issue

```
requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

the argument verify=False ignore the certificate but when you run your code it will show a warning message as output saying that the certificate is wrong, so you can add this other piece of code to don't get request warning showed:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

I know that doesn't answer your question but maybe you can try to see if without certificate you are able to get information without problem.

Comment: For pulling the data verify=False works. But you are right, for security reasons I have to use verify. But I noticed when I pass everyting as a single file the web service still starts.

Comment: so there is something else you are doing wrong part of the certificate, I would advice you to understand what is wrong without use certificate (so it will be easier to identify) and then you put the certificate back ;) maybe some header/body values that is wrong or crossdomain call (I already had this problem, you need just allow CORS on your flash API service) https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Hi there, I have a request that gives me the response of post request in the Postman by disabling the 'SSL certificate verification' in the setting option. But, if I get the python request code that provided by the Postman, I will receive the "SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed" error and adding the 'verify=False' does not help in this case, Is there any solution to get the response of the Postman in the python request script?

Comment: try to add this during the import: urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)